# Filling out an editable Pdf modify Radiobutton shapes

Tags: java, android, pdf, radio-button, itext

I have a fillable Pdf "prova.pdf" with 2 Radiogroup:
Radiogroup "olfatto" with 2 Radiobutton "eccellente" and "negativo";
Radiogroup "persistenza" with 2 Radiobutton "buono" and "insufficiente.

I use itext.jar 5.5.9 with Eclipse Neon and this code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FillForm {

public static final String SRC = "C:/Users/emanu/Desktop/prova.pdf";
public static final String DEST = "C:/Users/emanu/Desktop/risultato.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
File file = new File(DEST);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
new FillForm().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
}  
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("olfatto", "eccellente");
form.setField("persistenza", "buono");

stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
}  
}
```

In this code I just want to put a "cross" on Radiobutton "eccellente" and on Radiobutton "buono".
The code works but, at the end I get "risultato.pdf" where Radiobutton shapes are different from the origin: instead of original "cross" shapes I get "circle" usual shapes.
Can someone explain me why?
Here you can find "prova.pdf" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2t8jLeFdXzTYWZ0bE5YcFJMMUE/view?usp=sharing

and here you can find "risultato.pdf" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2t8jLeFdXzTaUN1eTNPTkExcGM/view?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Comment: Using itextpdf.jar 5.5.4 everything goes straight: Radiobutton shapes remain "cross" shapes. That's weird! Why?

Comment: Issues start from itextpdf.jar 5.5.7: Radiobutton shapes change from cross into circle. Why?

Comment: About Android, same issues using itextg: from 5.5.7 Radiobutton shapes in pdf form change. Why?